# Python pip site-packages

Tags: python, pip, installation

I have install my package via pip:

pip install mypackage

I see that it has put it in:

C:\Python364\Lib\site-packages\mypackage

when I run python (I've checked it is 3.6.4) I try to import a function from my module:

> > > from mypackage import version
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: cannot import name 'version'

When I print sys.path site-packages is even there:
'C:\Python364\Lib\site-packages',

I normally put all my binaries in with my main .py file and all imports work like this. However now I am trying to install from a .whl file and it can't import.

Answer (score 0):

Forget it. As it mypackage is now sitting in a folder called mypackage there is another level of indirection:

> > > from mypackage.mypackage import version

works!